# ASP.net 5 Web API 2 Password Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want a really simple Authentication in ASP.net 5

All you need to Authenticate is a Password. No UserManager or any sort of this thing.

How does the login Action looks like for that or how do I have to proceed to achieve that?

Edit: 
The password is a global password, not for each individual user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested this so it is just a starting point. 
You would need to implement a custom AuthenticationHandler.

Something like:

```
class PasswordAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<PasswordAuthenticationOptions>
{
    public PasswordAuthenticationHandler (PasswordAuthenticationOptionsoptions)
    {
        //set fields needed from options        
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
    {
        //get the password out of the Request and create claims collection
        ...
        var claimsId = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Options.AuthenticationType);
        return new AuthenticationTicket(claimsId, new AuthenticationProperties());// can use AuthenticationProperties to set additional propertiues needed in ticket
    }

    // override ApplyResponseChallengeAsync

 }
```

Create PasswordAuthenticationOptions that inherits from AuthenticationOptions.

Create OWIN middleware

```
public class PasswordAuthenticationMiddleware : AuthenticationMiddleware<PasswordAuthenticationOptions>
{
    public delegate Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> CredentialValidationFunction(string id, string secret);

    public PasswordAuthenticationMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, PasswordAuthenticationOptions options)
        : base(next, options)
    {}

    protected override AuthenticationHandler<PasswordAuthenticationOptions> CreateHandler()
    {
        return new PasswordAuthenticationHandler(Options);
    }
}
```

Then in Startup.cs you would use it like:

```
app.Use<PasswordAuthenticationMiddleware>(options);
```

You should be able to lock things down with the Authorize attribute on class, method or adding it as a global Filter.

I suggest you check out:
http://leastprivilege.com/2015/10/12/the-state-of-security-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6-authorization/
https://github.com/leastprivilege/AspNet5AuthorizationPlayground/tree/master/src/Authentication

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement the easiest way:

1. Check password inside api controller's action.
2. Set some generated or predefined cookies or return response with a token.
3. Create custom ActionFilter and check your cookies or token(inside the query string or http request headers) for `Authorization`